# Difference between the `event loop phases` such as `I/O callback` and `poll`

Tags: node.js, event-loop, single-threaded

I am unable to understand the difference between the two phases `I/O callback` and `poll` while reading through the mechanism of `event loop` of Node.js.

My understanding is as follows. Please correct if it's wrong: 
For example, When we try to read the file asynchronously, the `poll` phase receives the I/O instruction to read the file (so, the reading the file happens in poll phase?) and adds the `callback` of `fs.readFile()` to the `I/O callback` phase (callback of `fs.readFile` executes in `I/O callback` phase?).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think no one can explain this better than the [Node.js official docs](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/event-loop-timers-and-nexttick/).

Some key parts:

> What is the Event Loop?
>
> ---
>
> The event loop is what allows Node.js to perform non-blocking I/O
> operations — despite the fact that JavaScript is single-threaded — by
> offloading operations to the system kernel whenever possible.
>
> Since most modern kernels are multi-threaded, they can handle multiple
> operations executing in the background. When one of these operations
> completes, the kernel tells Node.js so that the appropriate callback
> may be added to the poll queue to eventually be executed. We'll
> explain this in further detail later in this topic.
>
> Event Loop Explained
>
> ---
>
> When Node.js starts, it initializes the event loop, processes the
> provided input script (or drops into the REPL, which is not covered in
> this document) which may make async API calls, schedule timers, or
> call process.nextTick(), then begins processing the event loop.
>
> The following diagram shows a simplified overview of the event loop's
> order of operations.

```
   ┌───────────────────────┐
┌─>│        timers         │
│  └──────────┬────────────┘
│  ┌──────────┴────────────┐
│  │   pending callbacks   │
│  └──────────┬────────────┘
│  ┌──────────┴────────────┐
│  │     idle, prepare     │
│  └──────────┬────────────┘      ┌───────────────┐
│  ┌──────────┴────────────┐      │   incoming:   │
│  │        poll           │<─────┤  connections, │
│  └──────────┬────────────┘      │   data, etc.  │
│  ┌──────────┴────────────┐      └───────────────┘
│  │        check          │
│  └──────────┬────────────┘
│  ┌──────────┴────────────┐
└──┤    close callbacks    │
   └───────────────────────┘
```

> note: each box will be referred to as a
> "phase" of the event loop.
>
> Each phase has a FIFO queue of callbacks to execute. While each phase
> is special in its own way, generally, when the event loop enters a
> given phase, it will perform any operations specific to that phase,
> then execute callbacks in that phase's queue until the queue has been
> exhausted or the maximum number of callbacks has executed. When the
> queue has been exhausted or the callback limit is reached, the event
> loop will move to the next phase, and so on.
>
> Since any of these operations may schedule more operations and new
> events processed in the poll phase are queued by the kernel, poll
> events can be queued while polling events are being processed. As a
> result, long running callbacks can allow the poll phase to run much
> longer than a timer's threshold. See the timers and poll sections for
> more details.
>
> NOTE: There is a slight discrepancy between the Windows and the
> Unix/Linux implementation, but that's not important for this
> demonstration. The most important parts are here. There are actually
> seven or eight steps, but the ones we care about — ones that Node.js
> actually uses - are those above.
>
> Phases Overview
>
> ---
>
> timers: this phase executes callbacks scheduled by setTimeout() and
> setInterval(). pending callbacks: executes I/O callbacks deferred to the next loop iteration. idle, prepare: only used internally. poll: retrieve new I/O events; execute I/O related callbacks (almost all with the exception of close callbacks, the ones scheduled by timers, and setImmediate()); node will block here when appropriate. check:
> setImmediate() callbacks are invoked here. close callbacks: e.g.
> socket.on('close', ...). Between each run of the event loop, Node.js
> checks if it is waiting for any asynchronous I/O or timers and shuts
> down cleanly if there are not any.